# Magento 2.2.8 - sitemap.xml contains "pub" DIR in the URL, It should be without "pub" directory in the URL

Tags: magento2, cron, sitemaps, magento2.2.8, cronjobs

**Preconditions**

> app/etc/env.php

```
'directories' => [ 'document_root_is_pub' => true ],

'MAGE_MODE' => 'production',
```

- `document_root_is_pub` is `true`
- `MAGE_MODE` is have `production` value

> sitemap.xml

- Filename : sitemap.xml
- Path : /media/

> Admin => Stores => Configuration => General => Web:

- Base Urls => Base URL for User Media Files =>{{unsecure_base_url}}media/
- Base URLs (Secure) => Secure Base URL for User Media Files => {{secure_base_url}}media/

---

---

> **But while generating the sitemap.xml via cron**

**Expected result**

- `sitemap.xml` index urls to sitemap should be 
  https://magento-site/media/sitemap-1-1.xml

**Actual result**

- `sitemap.xml` urls look like
  https://magento-site/pub/media/sitemap-1-1.xml

---

---

> **NOTE** : **When sitemap is generated from `admin` panel `sitemap` contains the proper urls, But somehow with `cron` it comes wrong url (contains `pub` in the url)**

---

---

**Most likely reason (Might be) But not in my case**

> Sometime problem happens when running the sitemap generation through
>   bin/magento cron:run from outside of the Magento directory.

- e.g our magento code is in /var/www/src, if I run php `src/bin/magento cron:run` from `/var/www` the urls will contain **src** as part of the
  baseurl.
- Running from the magento directory, e.g `php bin/magento cron:run` from
  `/var/www/src`, works as expected.
- **But** my **cron** is generating from `/var/www/src`
- And Running from **ADMIN** UI - Site generate will also works as
  expected.

> *Any solution or advise will be really helpful.*

Comment: I think as you have set document_root_is_pub it true so you  base_url will be like https://magento-site/pub/ that's why it will added pub in your URL. Please check by echo this {{unsecure_base_url}}media/ OR try {{(un)secure_base_url}}media/

Comment: Thanks for the comment, let me check that.

Comment: this is acknowledged internal issue magento please look -> https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/5321

Answer (score 4):

The reason is the way `getBaseUrl` function implemented on `Magento\Store\Model\Store`.

```
    public function getBaseUrl($type = UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_LINK, $secure = null)
    {
        ...
                case UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA:
                    $url = $this->_getMediaScriptUrl($this->filesystem, $secure);
                    if (!$url) {
                        $path = $secure ? self::XML_PATH_SECURE_BASE_MEDIA_URL : self::XML_PATH_UNSECURE_BASE_MEDIA_URL;
                        $url = $this->getConfig($path);
                        if (!$url) {
                            $url = $this->getBaseUrl(UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_WEB, $secure)
                                . $this->filesystem->getUri(DirectoryList::MEDIA);
                        }
                    }
                    break;
        ...
    }
```

If you don't have a value set for `Base URL for User Media Files` (and/or `Secure Base URL for User Media Files`) under `Store > Settings > Configuration > General > Web > Base URLs` (and/or `Base URLs (Secure)`) then `$url = $this->getConfig($path);` will return null, causing the last `if` condition create the `$url`.

As it's seen, that if condition has a wrong implementation of combining base **URL** with media **Directory**.

When you are running your cronjob under `/var/www/src`, media directory is under `pub/media/`. Because of the problematic part of the function, here how your base media URL gets created:

```
if (!$url) {
   $url = $this->getBaseUrl(UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_WEB, $secure) //"https://magento-site/"
       . $this->filesystem->getUri(DirectoryList::MEDIA); //"pub/media/"
     // = "https://magento-site/pub/media/"
}
```

**Solution** is to set;

- `Store > Settings > Configuration > General > Web > Base URLs > Base URL for User Media Files` value to `{{unsecure_base_url}}media/`,
- `Store > Settings > Configuration > General > Web > Base URLs > Secure Base URL for User Media Files` value to `{{secure_base_url}}media/`,

and refresh `Configuration` cache.

Comment: Agree with it. It's a setting issue.

Answer (score 1):

Media directory is always in "pub" and the actual result is correct but when you want to browse it, you don't need to put "pub" in the URL. Try the direct URL: `https://magento-site/media/sitemap-1-1.xml`

bydefault, magento `.htaccess` or `nginx.sample` file works like there is no need to put "pub" in the url but all the files and folders reside in "pub" folder and can be accessed without "pub" in the website domain.